# How to change outline color on TextInputLayout from material component?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, material-components-android

I got an error that says:

> Error inflating class
> com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

when implementing `TextInputLayout` from the material component.
Actually, I have resolved the problem by put material theme on my root layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
tools:context=".LoginActivity"
**android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar"**
android:padding="20dp">
```

But the outline color and the font changed, what should I do to make the outline color back to my `colorAccent`?

Answer (score 1):

Add this line : `app:boxStrokeColor="?attr/colorAccent"`